# Where does compiled typescript files reside in an Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just started learning Angular 2. The tutorials which I'm following mentioned that all the compiled files go into the `dist` folder. By compiled files, he meant the typescript files which got transpiled to javascript.

But I didn't get any `dist` folder when I created my project using Angular 2 CLI. Attached is a snapshot of my project structure. 
Note: There're few folders that were created by me at a later stage and were not part of default angular2 structure.

[image]

Also, when I looked into tsconfig.json file, it had following code.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Since there's `dist` directory mentioned in `outDir` property of the object then my project must have a dist folder somewhere. Am I missing something here?

Comment: if you are using `cli` you will not have a compiled file separately

Comment: @Aravind Then what exactly is happening here? Could you give some more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you will run the compiler, it will create a folder with name `dist`. Try to run `ng build` command if you have used `Angular CLI`. After this command the compiler will compile `ts` into `js`, make bundles and put them into the `dist` folder.

Comment: Should I use ng build when the project is in the development phase? And if on using ng build command the ts files will be compiled to js, then how exactly is my project working currently? I mean the pages are getting rendered then it must be the javascript code, right?

Comment: @KartikChauhan when you run `ng serve` in development mode the application is compiled and served in memory, if you didn't build your project. So for production environment you need to build your project and copy `dist` folder content to the server and than it will serve compiled code.